# como fazer com que uma variavel pegue um valor de uma pagina e passe para outra

Tags: php, mysql

tenho esse codigo abaixo.

```
<?php
       include '../conexao.php';

       $sth = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM comanda');
       $sth->execute();
       ?>
      
                       <?php
                       foreach ($sth as $res) {
                           extract($res);
                       ?>
                           <center>
                               <ul>
                                   <a href="#.php"><img id="efeito" src="../img/<?= $num_com ?>.png"></a>
                               </ul>
                           </center>
                       <?php
                       }
                       ?>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

aqui a linha de codigo com o "href" traz um dado do banco e usa no $num_com. 
preciso fazer com que quando eu selecionar uma comanda(imagem) ele pegue o valor especifico da variavel e armazenar em outra para ser usada em um insert futuramente.
como posso fazer isso ?

desde já obrigado pela atenção.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pode fazer criando um "Receptor de GET" no e executar uma função de insert no banco.

Vou demonstrar a lógica e você implementa de acordo com seu cenário!

1. Primeiro, vamos imaginar que abaixo está de onde sairá o valor:

**www.localhost/pegaValor?valor=2**  <-  Aqui temos o valor 2 sendo passado através do método GET em uma variável chamada **valor**

2. Depois é preciso receber esse valor, no caso vamos receber na página: **pegaValor** que ficará assim:

$valor = $_GET['**valor**'];  <- Aqui é onde vai receber o valor, a partir daqui é sucesso, você agora só precisa dar um insert no BD.

$sql = "insert into TABELA ('nome_coluna') VALUE = '$valor';"

Estude: Passagem por parâmetro $_GET e $_POST (Esses você deve dominar)

Comment: obrigado pela dica, mas não consegui executar.
preciso fazer com que ao clica em uma imagem, o valor dela seja direcionada para outra pg e seja armazenada em uma variavel.
ali como você me disse, eu precisaria de name para cada imagem para fazer funcionar, ali basicamente eu fiz um array e fiz com que ele ficasse exibindo as imagens ate chegar ao ultimo numero disponivel no banco

Comment: Você pode fazer passagem de valor utilizando: 
<a href="paginaRecebevalor?valor=142"> <img src="caminhodaimg.png"> </a>

Comment: deu certo marcos, muito obrigado pela atenção e pela dica.
sucesso e felicidade a você.

Comment: De nada amigo, não esqueça de dar o checked para mostrar aos outros como resolver o problema <3 até a próxima.